# Direct2d memory consumption

Tags: c++, direct2d

I'm testing Direct2D program.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819062(v=vs.85).aspx

When I Compile and run the program D2DCircle.exe and see Task Manager's memory column, about 19 MByte is used (or allocated ?)

And I run a little bigger program using some brushes and geometries, Task Manager's memory column display about 30MByte.

Why direct2d use a lot of memory so much?

Comment: Direct2D was written to take advantage of your machine's resources.  Calling 30MB a lot of memory was appropriate in the previous century, it is less than 0.75% of what's available today.

Answer (score 1):

Direct2D may cache some rendered primitives (as bitmaps) in memory. As not everything there is rendered by GPU directly.

GDI+ is also quite greedy in this respect.

You can compare it with my [Sciter](http://www.terrainformatica.com/sciter/main.whtm) engine. If you start just sciter.exe it will use Direct2D backend but if you will run it as `sicter.exe sciter-gfx=gdi` it will use GDI+.
If you compare speed of the same stuff rendered in D2D and GDI+ you will discover that 30mb is simply nothing.